# PSD slicing good practices

Tags: html, slice, psd

I'm managing the development of a website (new job) and we are currently on the slicing phase of the template, and I hear a lot of things of what we should and should not do while slicing... so what are the good practices you experienced developers do?

What formats should the images be?
Html conformation level (strict, transitional etc)
what tags should and should not be used
etc etc...

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best practice I can suggest to you is not to let Photoshop handle generating the HTML. It'll be an awful, non-semantic mess. Slice the image apart and do the HTML/CSS yourself.